# Returning iterator seems to invalidate it

Tags: c++, iterator

I'm returning iterator from my fnc after I used it and this iterator at the point of returning points to some character but after this fnc returns it the returned iterator doesn't point to that character anymore. What am I doing wrong?

```
typename std::string::const_iterator return_iterator(const std::string& line)
{
    auto beg = line.begin();  
/*here I'm moving this iterator and assing to it i.e.*/  
    beg = line.begin() + some_position;
    return beg;//at this point it points to a character
}  

void other_fnc(const std::string& line)
{
auto pos = return_iterator(line);//after this fnc returns pos points to some rubbish
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Please provide a minimal case that compiles and demonstrates the problem.

Comment: It looks unlikely that this could be the case unless "some position" is beyond the length of the string (i.e. equal to or past ::end()).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume, the actual code probably has templates (`typename` debris) and probably they are not referenced correctly in function argument of return type.

The following code works as expected:

```
const int some_position = 2; 

template <typename T>
typename T::const_iterator return_iterator(const T& line)
{
     typename T::const_iterator beg = line.begin(); 
     beg = line.begin() + some_position;
     return beg;//at this point it points to a character
}  

void other_fnc(const std::string& line)
{
    std::string::const_iterator pos = return_iterator(line);
    std::cout << "character to 2: " << *pos << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    std::string str = "Hello world";
    other_fnc(str);
}
```

Verify your code according to it. If you are doing something else, update your question.

(PS: I got rid of `auto` of C++11, as I don't have the compliant compiler at the moment)

Answer (score 1):

As the example code that you posted does not compile (`typename std::string::const_iterator` should be simply `std::string::const_iterator`), and fixing this error allows the code to [run as expected](http://codepad.org/Sa61J4jI), I am guessing that the actual code is a bit different.

This sounds to me like a case of a `std::string` parameter being copied by value and the reference counting being somehow disrupted before the `const_iterator` is accessed. For example, this signature:

```
std::string::const_iterator return_iterator(std::string line)
                                                   // ^ Notice: Not passing by
                                                   //           reference
```

passes the string by value. Because of COW, the copy is shared, but the moment that the function calls `line.begin()`, the *non-const* string member function `std::string::begin()` is called, meaning that a new copy of the underlying string is typically created. The non-const `iterator` that is returned is then converted implicitly to a `const_iterator` (a perfectly valid conversion).

**EDIT:** To demonstrate my point, take a look at the output of the following version that was modified to pass the `line` parameter to `return_iterator()` by value:

```
#include <cassert>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

std::string::const_iterator return_iterator(std::string line)
{
    std::string::const_iterator beg = line.begin();
    std::cout << "In return_iterator(), &(*line.begin()) is " << static_cast<const void *>(&*beg) << '\n';
/*here I'm moving this iterator and assing to it i.e.*/
    beg = line.begin() + 3;
    return beg;//at this point it points to a character
}

void other_fnc(const std::string& line)
{
    std::string::const_iterator pos = return_iterator(line);//after this fnc returns pos points to some rubbish
    std::cout << "In other_fnc(), &(*line.begin()) is " << static_cast<const void *>(&*line.begin()) << '\n';
    assert(*pos == line[3]);
}

int main()
{
    std::string line = "This is a test.";
    other_fnc(line);
}
```

http://codepad.org/K9yaWqWA

The assertion now fails. Also, notice that the addresses of `*line.begin()` are different.

Comment: Note that even if the signature uses `const std::string&`, returning an iterator could cause problems if the function is called as `return_iterator("foo")` or anything similar that constructs a temporary string and passes a constant reference to the temporary.  I'm guessing that is what happens in OP's real code.

Comment: @AndréCaron: True. That could be the problem.